vue project doesnt work with vue-facing-decorator
i just learn about vue3 with ts using vue-router and vue-facing-decorator. i didnt making much changes with the initiate project because i just learn it.
i just follow this
npm quick start
but my code turn into this when i run it
enter image description here
i already install
"vue-facing-decorator": "^3.0.4",

and make
"experimentalDecorators": true,

in my tsconfig.app.json
here is my Dasboard.vue
<template>
    <p>testing dasboard</p>
</template>

<script lang="ts">
import { Vue, Component } from "vue-facing-decorator"


@Component
export default class Dasboard extends Vue {
    mounted() {
        console.log("log this")
    }
}

</script>

my App.vue
<script setup lang="ts">
import Dasboard from './components/Dasboard.vue';
</script>

<template>
  <Dasboard/>
</template>

here is my main.ts
import { createApp } from 'vue'
import './style.css'
import App from './App.vue'
import router from './routers/router'

createApp(App).use(router).mount('#app')

did anyone know about it, thank you.
solve the eror and seeing my template in my running web

Please don't use external links to images. SO's interface can handle inline images.
And would be good to post error message itself (just text) not a screenshot -- the answer will come faster as per my experience.

thank you eddie, i appreciate it. i already solve it by adding @babel/plugin-proposal-decorators

I have the same issue as you, with a large code base. I tried a lot of things to make it work, but nothing made it work.
Right now I'm considering converting all the components to Options API.

i solve it by adding
@babel/plugin-proposal-decorators

@babel/plugin-proposal-class-properties

@vitejs/plugin-vue-jsx

and i use it in my vite config
export default defineConfig({
  plugins: [
    vue(),
    vueJsx({
      babelPlugins: [
        ['@babel/plugin-proposal-decorators', { legacy: true }],
        ['@babel/plugin-proposal-class-properties', { loose: true }]
      ]
    })

  ],
})


I tried this solution but it doesn't seem to work.
